# __VA_ARGS__ sees extra empty arg when invoked inside BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH

Tags: c++, variadic-macros, boost-preprocessor

My actual code example is quite complex, but I will try to summarize the behavior I am seeing with a simple illustration.

I have a macro that I want to be able to call individually, or multiple times as a part of a larger macro expansion:

```
#define DO_STUFF(name,...)   \
    STUFF1(name,__VA_ARGS__) \
    STUFF2(name,__VA_ARGS__) \
    STUFF3(name,__VA_ARGS__)
```

I can use `DO_STUFF(dave, int, char)` and similar variations directly in a source file and it generates the code I expect.

I also want to invoke big lists of the `DO_STUFF` macro with another list of inputs. In order to handle this case, I am using boost preprocessor with a sequence of tuples (or variadic sequence):

```
DO_LOTS_OF_STUFF(
      (dave, ball, pen)          \
      (alice, cat, dog, bicycle) \
      (peter, bird) )
```

My definition of `DO_LOTS_OF_STUFF` looks like:

```
#define DO_LOTS_OF_STUFF(SEQ)       \
   BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(              \
     INVOKE_DS, _,                     \
     BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SEQ_TO_SEQ(SEQ) \
   )

#define INVOKE_DS( r, data, elem )      \
   DO_STUFF(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM(elem)); \
```

When I invoke `DO_LOTS_OF_STUFF` as illustrated above, `STUFF1`, `STUFF2`, and `STUFF3` are all invoked with an extra comma at the end with an empty parameter.

If I break the expansion at the point that `DO_STUFF` is invoked (by changing its name), the preprocessor output looks like I expect:

```
DO_STUFF(dave, ball, pen)
DO_STUFF(alice, cat, dog, bicycle)
DO_STUFF(peter, bird)
```

If I break the expansion at the `STUFF1`, `STUFF2`, and `STUFF3` level, they appear in the output with an extra empty parameter:

```
STUFF1(dave, ball, pen,)
STUFF2(dave, ball, pen,)
STUFF3(dave, ball, pen,)
STUFF1(alice, cat, dog, bicycle,)
STUFF2(alice, cat, dog, bicycle,)
STUFF3(alice, cat, dog, bicycle,)
STUFF1(peter, bird,)
STUFF2(peter, bird,)
STUFF3(peter, bird,)
```

Is this just one of those things to avoid in preprocessor meta-programming like "don't use `##`"? "Don't use `__VA_ARGS__` in nested macros"?

Any advice on how to define `DO_STUFF` or  `DO_LOTS_OF_STUFF` to avoid this issue?

Comment: I find it really hard to believe you need to do this stuff. Or at least that you need to do it via the C preprocessor.

Comment: I assure you, I have a real world use case that makes sense. Most of what I am doing is accomplished with variadic templated types. The preprocessor is just being used to eliminate a lot of repetition in the final classes that use the templated types. The phony names above are just placeholders, but maybe they make it seem like my use case is trivial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what is going on.

Where I invoke `DO_STUFF` with `SEQ_FOR_EACH` I use `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM`:

```
#define INVOKE_DS( r, data, elem )      \
   DO_STUFF(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM(elem)); \
```

`BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM` turns a tuple `(a,b,c,d)` into comma separated tokens without the parenthesis `a,b,c,d`.

I assumed that that meant that `DO_STUFF(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM((a,b,c,d)))` would see 4 arguments, but in fact it still sees only one that is `a,b,c,d`.

This expansion:

```
#define DO_STUFF(name,...)   \
    STUFF1(name,__VA_ARGS__) \
    STUFF2(name,__VA_ARGS__) \
    STUFF3(name,__VA_ARGS__)
```

Is actually adding the extra empty parameter in this case because `__VA_ARGS__` is empty.

So the solution was pretty simple. I just created a different variant of the `DO_STUFF` macro that is used in the `DO_LOTS_OF_STUFF` case

```
#define DO_LOTS_OF_STUFF(SEQ)       \
   BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(              \
     INVOKE_DS, _,                     \
     BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SEQ_TO_SEQ(SEQ) \
   )

#define INVOKE_DS( r, data, elem )      \
   DO_STUFF_1(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM(elem)); \

#define DO_STUFF_1(tuple_args)   \
    STUFF1(tuple_args) \
    STUFF2(tuple_args) \
    STUFF3(tuple_args)
```